# fastapi Annotated does not work with Field - How to fix it?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have installed fastapi version 0.95.0

I have run.py working fine as below:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Path

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(test_id: str = Path(..., title="a test title", description="a test description")):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Api works fine
- in the `/doc` endpoint I see the title and the description showing right

---

I now want to use the new `Annotated` feature of fastapi which works fine:

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi import Path

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(test_id: Annotated[str, Path(..., title="a test title", description="a test description")]):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Api works fine
- in the `/doc` endpoint I see the title and the description showing right

---

I want to do some complex validation. so, let me go back and make a change to the first approach:

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class TestInput(BaseModel):
    test_id: str = Path(..., title="a test title", description="a test description")


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(inp: TestInput = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Api works fine
- in the `/doc` endpoint I the title and the description **not** showing

---

Now I wrap Path with Field

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = FastAPI()


class TestInput(BaseModel):
    test_id: str = Field(Path(..., title="a test title", description="a test description"))


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(inp: TestInput = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- Api works fine
- in the `/doc` endpoint I see the title and the description showing right

---

Now I want to use Annotated

```
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = FastAPI()


class TestInput(BaseModel):
    test_id: Annotated[str, Field(Path(..., title="a test title", description="a test description"))]


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(inp: TestInput = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The application crashes

```
File "pydantic/fields.py", line 497, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.infer
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 469, in pydantic.fields.ModelField._get_field_info
ValueError: `Field` default cannot be set in `Annotated` for 'test_id'
```

How should I use Annotated with the wrapper Field?

---

I just noticed that with Annotated I get the description an title without the need for Field

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi import Path
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

app = FastAPI()


class TestInput(BaseModel):
    test_id: Annotated[str, Path(..., title="a test title", description="a test description")]


@app.get("/test/{test_id}")
def test(inp: TestInput = Depends()):
    return "Hello world"


def main():
    uvicorn.run("run:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True, port=8001)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My problem is solved but anyway Field does not work with annotated. I am wondering if this is planned or a bug of fastapi